# dataframe values.tolist() datatype

Tags: python, pandas, tolist

I have a dataframe like this:

[image]

This dataframe has several columns. Two are of type `float`: `price` and `change`, while `volme` and `amount`are of type `int`.
I use the method `df.values.tolist()` change df to list and get the data:

```
datatmp = df.values.tolist()
print(datatmp[0])

[20160108150023.0, 11.12, -0.01, 4268.0, 4746460.0, 2.0]
```

The `int` types in `df` all change to `float` types.
My question is why do `int` types change to the `float` types? How can I get the `int` data I want?

Comment: Is this Pandas? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can convert column-by-column:

```
by_column = [df[x].values.tolist() for x in df.columns]
```

This will preserve the data type of each column.

Than convert to the structure you want:

```
list(list(x) for x in zip(*by_column))
```

You can do it in one line:

```
list(list(x) for x in zip(*(df[x].values.tolist() for x in df.columns)))
```

You can check what datatypes your columns have with:

```
df.info()
```

Very likely your column `amount` is of type `float`. Do you have any `NaN` in this column? These are always of type `float` and would make the whole column `float`.

You can cast to `int` with:

```
df.values.astype(int).tolist()
```

Comment: I want get the list array data with float and int two types and not and type, like  [20160108150023, 11.12, -0.01, 4268, 4746460, 2]

Answer (score 1):

I think the pandas documentation helps:

> DataFrame.values
>
> Numpy representation of NDFrame
>
> The dtype will be a lower-common-denominator dtype (implicit upcasting); that is to say if the dtypes (even of numeric types) are mixed, the one that accommodates all will be chosen. Use this with care if you are not dealing with the blocks.

So here apparently float is chosen to accomodate all component types. A simple method would be (however, most possibly there are more elegant solutions around, I'm not too familiar with pandas):

```
datatmp = map(lambda row: list(row[1:]), df.itertuples())
```

Here the `itertuples()` gives an iterator with elements of the form (rownumber, colum1_entry, colum2_entry, ...). The map takes each such tuple and applies the lambda function, which removes the first component (rownumber), and returns a list containing the components of a single row. You can also remove the `list()` invocation if it's ok for you to work with a list of tuples.

[Dataframe values property][1]
"http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html#pandas.DataFrame.values"

Comment: how use get_value()  instead, I want get the list array data with float and int two types

Comment: Maybe the approach I added is suitable for your needs?

Comment: how use approach  can get the result I want