# read csv and filter it based on the columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading data from csv file

```
reader = pd.read_csv(csvfile, sep=';', header=0)
list1=[]
list2=[]
```

here I read the csv file row by row:

```
for row in reader.itertuples():
            list1.append(row)
```

And then I look into the new list and filter it based on a condition:

```
for i in range(len(list1)):
         if(list1[i][5]==highestpointheight):
                list2.append(list1[i])
```

Now I have a list which is filtered based on the condition.

Is there any other efficient way so that I dont have two for loops?

Comment: Why would you not use Pandas [`.sort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort.html) on your `reader` object?

Comment: If you are using pandas, you should learn to work with data frames instead of converting them to python lists or numpy arrays.

Comment: @xvan : I need to have an output like this so that my app(graphQL resolver) can read it:  [Pandas(Index=5,ullid=1, sheetid=2, highestpointheight=332)], can I have this output with Pandas dataframes?

Comment: @User193452 If all fieds are of the same type, after filtering you can convert the data frame to a list via: `df.values.tolist()`

Comment: @xvan no they are different data types. so I should stick to the for loop for creating the list? p.s. your answer helped me for reading and filtering the csv and I will accept it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34838378/dataframe-values-tolist-datatype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pd.read_csv(csvfile, sep=';', header=0).loc[lambda df: df[5] == highestpointheight, :]
```

See http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-callable

Comment: Nice solution !

Answer (score 2):

You might want to reverse the order of the two operations:

try:

```
reader = reader[reader.iloc[:, 5] == highestpointheight] # filter the 6th column based on highestpointheight
for row in reader.itertuples():
        list1.append(row)
```