# How to prevent integers from being converted to floats when converting a data frame to a list?

Tags: python, pandas, list, csv, integer

How to prevent integers from being converted to floats when converting a data frame to a list?

I have a .csv file with 5 columns of data. The first four columns have no decimal points, while the last column does.

When I import this data into my script using "pd.read_csv", the data imports correctly, with the first 4 numbers as integers and the last as a float, like this:

```
1,1,10,0,1.0

1,1,11,0,0.6

1,1,12,0,0.0
```

BUT I need to convert this data into a list, and when I do it converts all the numbers into floats. I do not want this. The first four values need to be integers.

This is my current code, which, after its is converted to a list, provides a list where all numbers are float:

```
data_file_name = r'C:\Users\username\Desktop\FileName.csv'

data = pd.read_csv(data_file_name)  #<This part works and the data types are correct, the first 4 are integers
data2 = data.values.tolist() #<here is where everything gets converted to a float, even if it was defined as an int in the df.
```

This results in a list with the data formatted like this:

```
[[1.0, 1.0, 10.0, 0.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 11.0, 0.0, 0.6], [1.0, 1.0, 12.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```

When I need it to be formatted like this:

```
[[1, 1, 10, 0, 1.0], [1, 1, 11, 0, 0.6], [1, 1, 12, 0, 0.0]]
```

What can I do?

I've tried:

`[int(i,10) for i in data]`

But this returns this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Month'
```

Comment: Look at the [dtype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) argument in `pd.read_csv`

Comment: @Prune How does that duplicate help with `read_csv`?

Comment: The conversion logic is the critical part.

Comment: I've added in a new step I left out - the csv reading is working fine and the datatypes there are correct, but a decimal is added to the list even for the columns that are defined as ints in the df.

Comment: I found the answer to my question here, and this question also is asking exactly what I intended to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34838378/dataframe-values-tolist-datatype

Answer (score 1):

Use the `dtype` argument to control the datatypes.

```
pd.read_csv(data_file_name, dtype={0: "int64", 1: "int64", 2: "int64", 3: "int64", 4: "float64"})
```

Comment: Thank you, but this does not solve my issue. I've updated the question to be more clear. My data imports just fine, with the first 4 numbers importing as integers, and the last as a float. Its once this data is converted into a list that all numbers are converted to float.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34838378/dataframe-values-tolist-datatype

Comment: Thanks! I found that answer too, and I added it in the comment above. That answered my question.