# Keep data type integrity when converting df values to a list

Tags: python, list, dataframe, types

I am trying to insert all the data of a df into a table in an Oracle db. Before inserting the data into the table, I convert the df values into a list:

```
df_list = df.values.tolist()
```

but after some values that in the df were int64, become float numbers in the list, so I cannot insert the values in my db because those numbers are not int anymore. Is there a way to avoid this to happen? Is there a reason why is this happening?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/34838476/15035314

Comment: @Алексей the discussion solved my problem, I didn't find it before, thank you dDjBalcony and thank you  Алексей

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have some Nan values in the values column. And it makes Int values float.

To solve it. Before getting the list you can `fillna(0, inplace=True)` the column and then get the list.

for example:

```
df.fillna(0, inplace=True) #you can change it some other integer which you do not need
df.values = df.values.apply(int)
df_list = df.values.unique().tolist()
df_list.remove(0)
```